# Transforming a list of Models into a Map with an inner map using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Model>`:

```
[
  {parent: "parent", child: "child1", sensor: "wohoo"}, 
  {parent: "parent", child: "child1", sensor: "bla"}, 
  {parent: "parent", child: "child2", sensor: "wohoo2"}
]
```

and I want to transform it to a map `<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.

```
 {
   parent: {
    child1: ["wohoo", "bla"],
    child2: ["wohoo2"]  
   },
 }
```

I've tried this:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> test = currentlyReportingAgents
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Model::getParent,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getChild, Collectors.toList())));
```

but got some wired compilation errors.. What am I missing?

Edit: Added a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Please include the compilation errors in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution returns a different type:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Model>>> = ...;
```

To achieve what you want, you need to turn a `List<Model>` into a `List<String>` by the [`mapping(mapper, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> r = currentlyReportingAgents.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Model::getParent,
                        groupingBy(Model::getChild, mapping(Model::getChild, toList()))));
```

Comment: Nice. Add a `r.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " :: " + v));` and it all comes to life.